# How to reduce compression rate on the cover image?

Tags: facebook, compression

I don't know if this is the correct place to be asking this, but I don't know where else to ask it.

When we upload an image as cover photo for our facebook page, the quality is dreadful. This only happens when there are illustrations in it. When it's a full picture, everything is perfect.

So my question is, is there anything you can do to reduce the compression rate of facebook, or is it all upto them? For instance, are there any saving options in photoshop which are beneficial for the quality (on facebook)?

Comment: Ask it on the Facebook support forums? This isn't programming related at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try uploading a version of the cover that weighs less than 100kb. Do this by lowering the jpeg quality when saving from photoshop.
In my case I had a 158kb image which facebook compressed to 38kb. A 98kb version stayed untouched by fb...

Comment: Also, be sure to upload a jpeg. A png, even with a size < 100kb, will be compressed.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Since at least [June 2012](http://www.vancouverpov.ca/wp/social-media/tips-to-improve-facebook-cover-photo-quality/#comment-5483), the <100kb trick hasn't been working. What you can do is double the resolution of the source image, and introduce noise. Details in this [GD.SE question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/facebook-ways-to-preserve-image-quality-of-uploaded-images)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the displayed resolution of the Facebook Timeline cover photo (both for people and brands) is 851x315 pixels.

I suggest you create your cover with this resolution.

[More info here: What is the resolution of the cover photo in Timeline?](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-resolution-of-the-cover-photo-in-Timeline)

Comment: Ok thanks, the designer made a cover 851x314px instead of 315. Now it looks a little bit better.

Comment: @samn: For best results, make the cover photo source image double the size, i.e. 1700x630, and introduce noise. Details in this [GD.SE question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/facebook-ways-to-preserve-image-quality-of-uploaded-images)